# merge data frames by character and rowname

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, tidyr

I have two data frames like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(7),
              v2 = c("a1", NA, "a2", "a3", "a5", "a6", "a9"))


> df1
           v1   v2
1  0.39956187   a1
2  0.33711756 <NA>
3 -0.19583763   a2
4  0.04880812   a3
5 -2.07266374   a5
6 -0.83824743   a6
7  1.31302096   a9


df2 <- data.frame(pc1 = rnorm(5),
                  pc2 = rnorm(5))
rownames(df2) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a6", "a9")


> df2
           pc1         pc2
a1 -0.89865755 -0.32949632
a2 -0.05709327 -0.06923935
a3 -0.44229588  0.32089049
a6 -1.51754734 -0.34285758
a9  0.99955141 -0.62749542
```

`df1` has a column `v2` that contains character values that match the rownames of `df2`. But it also has `NA`s and may contains characters where no corresponding rownames in `df2` exists.

I now want to merge these data frames to one, like this:

```
           v1   v2           pc1         pc2
1  0.39956187   a1   -0.89865755 -0.32949632
2  0.33711756   NA            NA          NA
3 -0.19583763   a2   -0.05709327 -0.06923935
4  0.04880812   a3   -0.44229588  0.32089049
5 -2.07266374   a5            NA          NA
6 -0.83824743   a6   -1.51754734 -0.34285758
7  1.31302096   a9    0.99955141 -0.62749542
```

how can I do this. I would prefer a **dplyr** (**tydiverse**) solution.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `rownames_to_column` to create a column from row names and then do a `left_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df2, "v2") %>%
                   left_join(df1, .)
```